# BSOD "STOP 0x0000007B" after installing WIndows XP on external HDD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, external-hard-drive, bsod

I got a bsod saying:

STOP: 0x000007B (0xF78A2524, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

I know this seems to have been asked multiple times, but Í think I'm a different case. I just installed winxp professional on an external hdd, linux worked on that disk in the past. Now I get the bsod.

Does anyone know what has coused this. I've reinstalled windows severaltimes and deleted all partitions, any suggestions?

Comment: does it work if you remove the hard drive from the external enclosure and put it into the computer?

Comment: What do you mean? it's connected with an usb cable, can I remove it then?

Comment: Just to clarify... You are installing XP on a USB drive and it fails to boot and gives this error or?

Comment: @dan what method are you using to install XP on to the drive?

Comment: I'm installing windows xp professional on the external usb hard drive, the instalation is completed without any incidents. Then wen xp boots the bsod pops up. I'm installing winxp on the 'normal' way, with the windows xp live cd and then running the installer

Comment: @dan I thought that might be the case - WinXP does not support installing to a USB drive by default, and will crash if you do so (because it will, by default, disconnect and rediscover all USB as it boots - disconnecting the drive it's running from in the process and causing the STOP you are experiencing).

Comment: BSOD STOP code 0x000007B means INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE, which is pretty self-explanatory.  The bootloader loads the kernel (otherwise you wouldn't be able to get the BSOD) off USB using BIOS calls, but then the kernel has to switch to its own USB storage driver, which it doesn't have at that point, and crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP does not support booting from a USB drive without some tweaks. There also seems to be an issue with some hardware no matter what.  While the system recognizes the USB drive as it starts to boot, it drops the USB connection and the boot process fails.  There are several sites that detail what is needed.  Here is one to get you started [USB boot](http://www.ngine.de/article/id/8) ([mirrored here](http://fsadventures.com/2009/12/how-to-install-and-run-a-full-windows-xp-from-a-usb-drive/))

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, I've done the tutorial and I'm now crossing my vingers at the installation. The tutorial is of outstanding quality, all files the turial mentioned were present. exactly the way the tutorial mentioned them :D

Comment: It's accepted and you know what that means !!! THANK  You! you saved my day sir!

Comment: No problem.  I went through this for a clinet that wanted a bootable HD and we found it was not suitable for the mission critical nature of what they needed.  However, it seems to work for many people based on what I found at the time.  Good luck!