# BSOD error 0xF78A2524 when starting up (Windows XP on a USB thumbdrive)

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

Basically I had the same error as the one on this topic: [BSOD "STOP 0x0000007B" after installing WIndows XP on external HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/214636/bsod-stop-0x0000007b)

The link on the answer is dead and I can't find it on Google's cache either.

I'm installing Windows XP SP3HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool on a USB thumbdrive (connected to the back panel), and have gotten through the text mode setup (after hours of Googling and trial-and-error). The BSOD shows up after the reboot, and I can't get past it. Is there anything else that I can try (other than using a HDD for the OS)?

#### Hardware

- Intel Pentium E2200
- Gigabyte G31M-ES2L
- 2 GB Kingston DDR2 RAM
- 4 GB Sandisk Cruzer Blade (FAT32, formatted with HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool)
  No HDD is attached to the motherboard

#### Things I've tried

- [Modifying USB driver files](http://kemovitra.blogspot.com/2010/06/install-windows-xp-on-usb-thumb-drive.html)
- [Modifying ntdetect.com](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/112630-0x0000007b-blue-screen-error-during-text-setup/page__p__738009#entry738009)
- Disabling on-chip SATA mode

Comment: Is this hardware known to be good via a different installation? Sounds like you may have a hardware error.

Comment: Yep it's fine when XP is installed on a HDD. I actually spent the past 6 hours working on this, and figured out that the exact cause is that XP not being able to load USB drivers correctly (0x0000007B means INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE, and since the OS is on the USB thumbdrive, you can have a rough idea what happens in between). I'm still stuck at messing with the drivers though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full Windows desktop but just need to run a couple utilities, it might be better to just create a Windows 7-based "WinPE" installation on your USB disk.  You need to [download and install the Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5753), and here's [a Microsoft KB article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766092%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on the exact steps involved.

If you really need Windows XP for some reason, you might have better luck using [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) instead.